# Transfer files between raspberry pi and Multiple Linux OS computers?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, file-transfer

I am looking for a method to transfer files between Raspberry Pi and a computer with Linux OS on.
I need to do so without FileZilla file transfer.
I wonder if there is a script to do it automatically .

I have an array of files and a corrosponding array of IP's of the receiving Servers on a network how can i map the files to the servers and send them in turn .

any bit of advice is very much appreciated.

Comment: Seems that your title does not reflect the question well. You need to transfer to multiple computers.

Comment: yes ,exactly 
Sir in my graduation project i have a network to which i connect resbperry pi and group of computers (say 3 initially )and i need to send 3 files to 3 computers respectively .

Comment: Now that you have a command to do the transfer you need to learn to use `bash` -- the Linux shell/command language to write the loop you want.  There are lots of resources available on the internet to hep you do that.  Google bash, read, and learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's a little overdone, but you may want to check out [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/): Generally a deployment tool, but I'm using ist to handle all of my file transfers between all my 4 Raspi's, Uploading config files and starting/stopping services.

Answer (score 1):

So you need transfers files from Pi to multiple Linux computers. If you only have a limited number of computers you need to transfer to, then you can do so manually for each computer, using the [scp](https://linux.die.net/man/1/scp) command.
For example let's say the you need to transfer all files with extension `.c` found in directory `/foo`  in the Pi to the server named `barserver` in the directory `/foobar`. From the Pi you can run:

```
$ scp /foo/*.c username@barserver:/foobar/
```

Or equivalently from the server you can run:

```
$ scp username@piaddress/foo/*.c /foobar/
```

If you have so many servers that doing it manually would be tedious, then you could write a script.

Comment: what if i wanted to involve a loop in the script would it make sence

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Make sure you have thought about your problem fully and describe it clearly. If an answer has been helpful, just upvote it or accept it.